Sending Email alert to different email address and with different email body one after another in flow
I have to send 2 different emails to different customers one after another once condition met, I have arranged email alert from the flow with different as image attached here, the problem is only the last email will be sent, not the first one. has any one faced this issue and has any solutions?


Both should be sent. Try checking the Email Logs in Setup to see if the messages are being sent. It could be a problem with the recipient's inbox.

Nope, I did check, only one email i can see. that too last user email.

I found the issue finally, Both users has the same email address, Salesforce will sent to  1 email out of 2 if both email same. After setting different email address for both users, it worked.
